# How to find a DATE in a string

Tags: python, string, date

I am working on a project that reads a list in pdf and transforms the list into a .csv file, but when I read the pdf, the text is pass to a string, until that I have no problem, but I have to input a `"\n"` every time when I found a date, for example:

Like in the string:

```
'HELDER ALVES DE OLIVEIRA18/06/1986RENAN ALVES DE OLIVEIRA06/08/2005'
```

How I wanted:

```
'HELDER ALVES DE MEDEIROS;18/06/1986\NRENAN ALVES DE OLIVEIRA;06/08/2005\N'
```

So when I open the file .csv will be tabulated.

Comment: try using regular expressions https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'HELDER ALVES DE OLIVEIRA18/06/1986RENAN ALVES DE OLIVEIRA06/08/2005'
>>> re.sub('(\d\d\/\d\d/\d\d\d\d)', '\\1\n',s)
'HELDER ALVES DE OLIVEIRA18/06/1986\nRENAN ALVES DE OLIVEIRA06/08/2005\n'
```

Comment: While this will work if the input is expected to not contain errors, it's worth noting that this will match invalid dates, such as `56/36/2005`.

Comment: You always have to make assumptions on the input. What if the name contains a valid date (e.g. HELDER ALVES 01/01/2001 DE OLIVEIRA)? Anyway you are right. in certain cases this will not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the powerfulness of [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) module to a better use, as pointed out on a comment on the previous answer by [Jules Mazur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033027/jules-mazur) that you need to set some sort of filtering invalid dates, here is an example of that:

```
>>> s
'HELDER ALVES DE OLIVEIRA18/06/1986RENAN ALVES DE OLIVEIRA06/08/2005'
>>>
>>> re.findall(r'((?:[1-2][0-9]|0[1-9]|3[0-1])/(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2])/(?:[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]))', s)
['18/06/1986', '06/08/2005']
>>>
>>> re.sub(r'(?P<Date>(?:[1-2][0-9]|0[1-9]|3[0-1])/(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2])/(?:[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]))', '\g<Date>\n', s)
'HELDER ALVES DE OLIVEIRA18/06/1986\nRENAN ALVES DE OLIVEIRA06/08/2005\n'
```

You can check the detailed description of it in this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qE8yK4/1).
Also, you can find more advance `re` patterns for date and time, in the regex library